# What is the current status of Consequences of the Axiom of Choice website?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, online-resources

The book Consequences of the Axiom of Choice by Paul Howard and Jean E. Rubin is (or at least used to be) accompanied by a website with a large database of various forms of consequences of AC,  which also included the possibility of searching for models where these forms hold/do not hold, implication between the forms etc. This was certainly a useful resource for people interested in this topic.

As far as I remember, the website used to be http://consequences.emich.edu or http://consequences.emich.edu/conseq.htm. (At least that's what I found in my browser history.) More recently I saw links to [https://www.math.purdue.edu/~hrubin/JeanRubin/Papers/conseq.html](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Ehrubin/JeanRubin/Papers/conseq.html) You can see that these websites have been mentioned in several posts both [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Aconsequences.emich.edu) and [on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3Aconsequences.emich.edu). (The latter occurs less often, both [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Awww.math.purdue.edu/%7Ehrubin) and [at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3Awww.math.purdue.edu/%7Ehrubin), probably because it is more recent.) The links were mentioned in comments, both [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/556789/comments-containing-given-keyword-with-text-and-author?Word=consequences.emich.edu) and [at MO](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/556789/comments-containing-given-keyword-with-text-and-author?Word=consequences.emich.edu).

However, the website used to have some problems [already in the past](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/conversation/consequences-of-ac-website-is-down). At the moment, it seems that only one of the two links works. But even though the website is accessible, the actual searching for forms or models only returns errors.

So what I want to ask is:

- Are there some alternatives containing the same database? Did the website moved to a new url I am unaware of?
- Does anybody know about plans to revive these websites?
- Is there some possibility to use the database offline? (The description of the book at [AMS bookstore](http://bookstore.ams.org/surv-59) mentions a software which comes with the book. Is it freely available?)

Comment: I am aware that whether this question is on-topic or not is borderline. Since I consider this a very useful resource and I think information whether and where it is still accessible could be useful for many users of this site, I decided to post it. Of course, if the consensus is that it is off-topic and the question is closed, I'll have to accept that.

Comment: If I wanted to know erverything in greatest detail about some oscure conseqeunce of AC, I'd ping Asaf Karagila - probably much more complete than any dead database.. ;)

Comment: @Hagen: You could also ping me to ask about some dead database, or at least if that site is still alive...

Comment: Recently, a related question was posted on [mathoverflow.se]: [Wiki for consequences of axiom of choice?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/373775)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**A revamped database, called "Choiceless Grapher" is now available: https://cgraph.inters.co/.**
The data and code for the website are available at https://github.com/ioannad/jeffrey

This website has been created by [Ioanna M. Dimitriou](https://ioa.re/) along with Paul Howard.
Maybe interesting for future readers (in case sites go down again), [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20170718122931/https://boolesrings.org/ioanna/2016/12/13/choiceless-grapher-app/) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20161224212932/https://boolesrings.org/ioanna/2016/12/24/cgraph-predicates/) are some blog posts by Ioanna M. Dimitrou on creating this revamped website.

Comment: To complement Asaf's answer: I emailed Paul about the site a little less than 2 years ago. He indicated that the site went down when the computer it had been hosted from died. His idea was, rather than restore the site, to revamp it: "[we] are currently working on a new site which we hope will be more complete and user friendly than the old one ...  and we are planning on something which would be more of a community project than the old Consequences web site." Part of what he means at the end is that the hope is the new site will be easier to update. We'll see...

Comment: The website is now available at https://cgraph.inters.co/ ("Choiceless Grapher"); see also its GitHub page https://github.com/ioannad/jeffrey .